# Does mybatis support hot deploy?

Tags: mybatis

When a web application based spring has been launched, could the modifications to sql map file be reflected immediately? I'm using mybatis 3 and jrebel plugin, modifications to classes can be reflected instantly. I guess modifications to the sql map file can be hot deployed somehow, because I did similar things to ibatis before, but for now I've not researched into  mybatis source code. Does anyone know that?

Answer (score 1):

JRebel integration for MyBatis needs to be updated. Please file a feature request at the [forum](http://zeroturnaround.com/forums).